# Relationship between White Walkers and Children of the Forest

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

After viewing episode 5 of season 6 of *Game of Thrones*, we have come to know that

> the Children of the Forest created the White Walkers.

But it seems that the White Walkers attack the Children of Forest. My question is why they would do so, given their origin.

Comment: ... we don't know yet.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowback_(intelligence)

Comment: In fact this is a very popular [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TurnedAgainstTheirMasters).

Comment: **SPOILERS IN COMMENT** If somebody tied you to a tree, plunged a knife through your rib cage that granted you magical powers including the ability to raise the dead & immortality - but turned you into a monster - would you happily go along with them when they ask you to fight their battles for you, or would you use your new found power to dominate both sides?

Comment: @JamesTrotter considering that we don't know whether the man was a willing participant or not, that's not really a valid point.

Comment: @Catija the scene seems pretty self evident that he was not willing. You don't have to tie down the willing, and the willing often don't have fear in their eyes like that.

Comment: @cde so, if you were willing, you'd be able to simply sit still while they shoved a blade into your heart? Pretty sure not. He also may have been willing but never told what the process was... So the fear could still make sense. Lots of people have second thoughts when things move from hypothetical to actual.

Comment: Hey OP, don't you wonder what is the relationship with Jon and Daenerys ? Well, both questions we have no awnsers.

Comment: It's a bit like biochemical warfare - concocting a virus that ends up mutating and being incurable and infecting the people who made it. Much isn't known about the Children's intentions (other than that it was their last measure against the First Men, as they were facing possible extinction) - we don't know that they knew it would mutate and get out of hand. Whether they did or didn't, clearly they thought, at the time, that any extreme measure was worth the risk, when weighed against the survival of their kind.

Comment: That is the impression most get and many people see it as a sort of Skynet situation. Create something meant to defend you but then gets a mind of it's own and decides it doesn't want to help and instead wants to destroy you and everyone else.

Comment: In the show, yes, not exactly the same in the books though. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Walker

Comment: The TV show hasn't told us yet, and I doubt that the books have yet either. My personal theory is the Children created the WW to kill all humans, and then changed their mind about killing all the humans but had no way to call off the WW.

Answer (score 5):

It is not said either on the show or novel. The only thing certain is that the Children of the Forest created them to fight the First Men when they came to Westeros.

The Children of the Forest created a "weapon" so powerful they could not control, and for some reason the White Walkers turned against them.

But that's sadly everything there is about this relationship.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/what-does-the-night-king-really-want) about Night Kings' purpose and one of the answers there contained information you might find helpful. It said something like:

> The White Walkers were created centuries ago before the long night by the Children of the Forest as a weapon to fight back the first men as can be seen in the TV show.
>
> After the White Walkers were created both men and Children of the Forest had to fight them. They both made an alliance and were able to defeat the White Walkers (the Azor Ahai legend is from this period of time). After this, they built the wall and for some time the Children of the Forest even provided the Night Watch with Dragon Glass in the case of the Walkers came back.

From this it was pointed that the **magic** that created the White Walkers **didn't work as planned** so they had to unite and fight them.