# The mechanics of creating a White Walker

Tags: game-of-thrones

We saw a few episodes ago:

> Leaf creating a White Walker with what looks to be a Dragonglass dagger. It was unclear from that scene whether the stabbing itself initiates the transformation or if there are other rites being performed to create it.

However, given that both Dragonglass and Valyrian Steel are capable of destroying a White Walker, I wonder if both can also be used to create them. It seems unlikely, but am curious whether anyone can find any other evidence for an answer.

My hunch is that Valyrian Steel *cannot* create a White Walker because it is regularly used in combat against humans. The reason I find it unlikely is that in combat over the last 1000 years in Westeros, not a single killing created a White Walker, but the number of stabs to the heart from Valyrian Steel surely was >0.

It also seems that Dragonglass quickly fell out of use after the last long winter, due to its current scarcity in Westerosi arsenals. It also seems that even if they were used in human to human combat, they never led to the conversion of a human to White Walker much like Valyrian Steel.

So is it safe to say that:

> **only** the Children of the Forest are capable of creating White Walkers? Is that due to other rites/magic or simply the knowledge and ownership of dragonglass that gives them this ability?

Comment: Related to [Relationship between White Walkers and Children of the Forest](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53395/relationship-between-white-walkers-and-children-of-the-forest)

Comment: @AnkitSharma not sure how their origin is related to my question, unless you are implying that we don't know, which would be an acceptable answer. My question is looking for evidence that other factors other than the dragonglass stabbing was apparent in this scene. Perhaps dragonglass always had these powers but the Children of the Forest were the first to discover it. And since dragonglass and Valyrian Steel share characteristics in fighting the White Walkers, is there any evidence that Valyrian Steel could also create them?

Comment: The former one "we don't know".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know. Neither the show or the books go in depth regarding magical acts. All we know is that magic of the Children of the Forest is involved. But Valerian steel was not involved or mentioned or hinted that it was involved.

Everything the main characters know is from first hand experience fighting the White Walkers, and some rumor and legend from the First Men. Nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the Children of the Forest created the Night King in the scene that you mention. However, we do not know if they created any other White Walkers.

However in season 4 episode 4, "Oathkeeper", we see that the Night King can create White Walkers from baby boys:

So to answer your question, no not only the Children of the Forest can create White Walkers as we know that the Night King can too.